# how can i confer a decimal number into hex without using write hex

Tags: assembly, x86, hex

Write the program to convert a  decimal number to hex.
To convert a decimal number to hex we find the highest power of 16 the number is less than of equal to.
We do this be starting at 1 and comparing the number N to 1

```
If 1 < N we try 16
if 16 < N we try 256
```

until we find the highest power.

```
I would keep the powers in an array like 1,10h, 100h, 1000h, up to 100000000h
```

Then we convert by successive division

```
Ex    convert 834 to hex
834/256  = 3 + r 78
78/16       = 4 + r 14
14/1         = E + r0
```

The hex number is 34Eh

You may leave you answer without a leading zero if the first digit is a letter, but 0AB3h is better than AB3h. However you must have the h as the last portion of the answer

```
mov edx,offset msg
call writestring
call readint
mov tempt1,eax
div eax
.if(tempt<1)
    mov eax,16
.elseif()
.else
.endif
ret
```

Comment: can anyone suggest how to do this. I only know how to divide numbers but how can i get remainder ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a do-my-homework-for-me website. Please give us some evidence that you have at least tried.

Comment: I have added my starting code but i am lost. Don't know what to do next.

Comment: No need to use `div`. `x SHR 4` is `x / 16` and `x AND 15` is `x % 16`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy if you start by converting to binary.

I am assuming that your input string is ascii (for bcd you can ommit the first subtraction.)

1. set your holding register to 0.
2. starting with the least significant digit subtract '0' (the character to convert  to bcd)
3. multiply the digit by 10^n where n is it's position
4. add to your digit to your temp register
5. repeat until finished.
6. now each byte holds 8 bits or two nibbles and each nibble is equivalent to one hexadecimal digit. copy the byte and and it with 0xf to get the low nibble.
7. if it is greater than 9 add '@' (which is just before A)
8. otherwise add '0'
9. bitshift your holding register by 4 to get the next digit
10. loop until your holding register is empty.